# Changing components element colour with class binding

Tags: vue.js

I have a component which is being used in different places but at once place, the colour of the link need to change. I tried the following but it doesn't my work.

component

```
<section class="contact__info">
    <div class="details">{{days}}</div>
    <div>
        <a :href="'telephone'">
            <strong>{{telephone}}</strong> 
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<style lang="scss">
.contact__info{
   a {
     color: grey;
     font-weight: bolder
   }
}
</style>
```

I am calling it as following in the page which needs the colour change for the `anchor` in that component and which is not working is as follows

```
<CallWidget 
  :class="{anchor : isFooter}"
  title="Call Us:" 
  days="Mon - Fri" 
  telephone="0123"
/>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        isFooter: true
      }
    },
  };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .anchor {
    a {
      color: white;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class is inside a child component you need to add `/deep/` or `>>>` before it to tell Vue to check inside child components.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  /deep/ .anchor {
    a {
      color: white;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Take a look at https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: Thanks, but does the class need to be same name as of component? and also do I need an object in my class binding like in the question or can simply style it using /deep/?

Comment: `/deep/` will just tell Vue to search element with `.anchor` class inside child component, in your case inside `CallWidget`. The class can be whatever, it can be and object like inside your question or just a string